# Is it possible for emulator Android to connect to different network?

Tags: android

I have two different Wifi that i can connect to my laptop, one from the office and the other is hotspot wifi from my phone.

is it possible for my Laptop connect to my office wifi and the Emulator Android connect to my handphone hotspot wifi ?

I am using Nox for the Android Emulator.

UPDATE :
What !? That's it ? No other opinion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The android Emulator using your current laptop's WIFI hardware. So it's impossible for it to connect another WIFI.

Comment: Then what if i use Virtual Windows using VirtualBox, is it going to be the same result too ?